Autodesk Viewer Extension: removeProperty() not working
I am trying to add and remove properties in the Autodesk Viewer property panel. The new properties should appear when a user clicks on a particular property (already in the panel). Adding and removing the property once works. However, subsequent clicks do not work.
I have used this code inside an Autodesk.Viewing.UI.PropertyPanel class:
onPropertyClick(property, event) {
  this.active = !this.active; // whether to display the new category
  if (this.active && property.name == "Sensor A") {
      this.addProperty("test", "value", "category 1")
    } else if (!this.active && property.name == "Sensor A") {
      this.removeProperty("test","value","category 1")
    }
 }

The problem is that once the property is removed, a second call to addProperty() always returns false. It looks like the property was not removed properly.
I am using vanilla js and no framework that could mess with the code.
Secondly, how can I remove a category? The category is not automatically removed when the 'last' property is removed.
I did not found anything in the PropertyPanel.js source code or the documentation.

Here's a simple implementation of a custom property panel that adds and removes its properties:
class CustomPropertyPanel extends Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel {
    constructor(viewer, options) {
        super(viewer, options);
        this.counter = 0;
        this.addProperty(`Prop ${this.counter++}`, "ADD", "Custom");
    }

    onProperties() {}

    onPropertySet() {}

    onPropertyClick(event) {
        switch (event.value) {
            case "ADD": // if the value of the property is ADD, add another property
                this.addProperty(`Prop ${this.counter++}`, Math.random() < 0.5 ? "ADD" : "REMOVE", "Custom");
                break;
            case "REMOVE": // if the value of the property is REMOVE, remove this property
                this.removeProperty(event.name, event.value, event.category);
                break;
        }
    }
}

// ... and later, after the viewer has been initialized ...

viewer.getExtension("Autodesk.PropertiesManager").setPanel(new CustomPropertyPanel(viewer, {}));

This seems to be working as expected. Could it be an issue with your onPropertyClick method signature? It looks like it should be onPropertyClick(event) and not onPropertyClick(property, event).

But in your example, counter and random lead to a "new" property each time it is created. My question was about removing and recreating the exact same property. I also verified that the actual property is never removed from the property tree (only not visible anymore). Is this behavior intentional?

Ah, so you mean removing and re-introducing a property with the same name/category is not working as expected? I'll need to look into that. However, looking at the implementation of the removeProperty method, the property should be completely removed from the UI. If that's not the case, there might be some issue in the removal logic.

Yes, exactly. And probably because of this, the category will not be removed from view once the last property of it is deleted and the category becomes empty.
